# getting the meaning of an expression in c++

Tags: c++, pointers

I am reading a legacy code in **c++** which defines an array and then assigns to a variable (see below). Though I've used pointers and references in the past, I am not certain about the meaning of this expression. Questions:
1. what is the meaning of this expression ?
2. why is the outer pointer necessary when there is already another pointer in (WORD*) ?
Thanks in advance !

```
BYTE txbuf[16]; 
...
WORD crc = *((WORD*)(&txbuf[2]));
```

Comment: What specifically are you asking about in 1.?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Question 2 first:
There's no "outer pointer" - the inner `*` is part of a cast to pointer type, the outer `*` is dereferencing the resulting pointer.

Question 1:
Breaking it down into parts, it means the same as this:

```
BYTE txbuf[16]; 
...
BYTE* byte_pointer = &txbuf[2];
WORD* word_pointer = (WORD*) byte_pointer;
WORD crc = *word_pointer;
```

Answer (score 4):

- `&txbuf[2]`: get the address of the third item inside `txbuf`.
- `(WORD*)(&txbuf[2])`: C-style cast the result of `&txbuf[2]` to `WORD*`.
- `*(/* ... */)`: dereference the whole thing, producing a `WORD&`.

Comment: An alternative would be `*((WORD*)(txbuf+2))` but for some reason the idiom of using array indexing (`[]`) and then taking its address is common. Unwrapping array indexing you really have `&*(txbuf+2)` which is 'go to the third element, dereference it and then take its address...

Comment: (2) and (3) is done to cast two consecutive 1-byte numbers (`BYTE`) to a one two-bytes number (`WORD`, or whatever size it has)

Comment: Also worth pointing out that the expression has undefined behavior. In practice there's no guarantee that a statically declared array of `BYTE` (assumed to be `(un)signed char`) will be aligned compatibly with `WORD` (assumed `(u)int16_t` . It's legal to cast something declared as `WORD` to `BYTE` but not guaranteed back again.